# upload a blob to server using fs

Tags: node.js, file-upload, blob, fs, blobstore

i have a site that records audio and returns a blob, goal is to send that blob from the client side vanilla javascript via fetch api or something, then send it to the node.js server then from there upload it to a certain directory using somehitng like fs.

```
function audio() {
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type': 'audio/mp3;' });
    // i want to send this blob to the back end server via fetch API
}
```

here is my backend

```
//----------Upload
spokenBio.post('/upload-spoken-bio', async (req, res) => {

    //waiting to get the blob or the file via req.body and somehow turn it into a real file write it 
    //into the server disk

})
```

Comment: couldn't you just base64 the Blob.arrayBuffer() and send it in the POST body?

Comment: @Maciej21592 NO! There is *no* reason for base64 encoding in this case.  If you do that, you're adding 33% overhead to the file, for zero benefit.

Comment: ah well, he should just pass the buffer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send, you can use the Fetch API:

```
fetch('/upload-spoken-bio', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: blob
});
```

On the server, you can simply do something like:

```
req.pipe(
  fs.createWritableStream('/some/path/file')
);
```

Of course, make sure you're trusting the data here, and don't let the user specify the path.

Comment: do you mean ````req.body.pipe()````??